# is there any way to take the data part from netcdf file using netcdf reader using scala code?

Tags: scala

```
def loadNetCDFDim(uri: String): List[String] = {
  val netcdfFile = NetCDFUtils.loadNetCDFDataSet(uri)
  val vars = netcdfFile.getDimensions()
  var list: List[String] = List()
  for (i <- 0 to vars.size - 1) {
    val k = vars.get(i).getFullName list ++= List(k)}
    list
  }
```

through this we got all the dimensions in that netcdf file. in this way is it possible to take the data part

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: a netcdf file contains data part also from for example :
data: 
lat = 1,2,3,4,5
lon = 3,5,8,6,8
how we can take this data from netcdf file